# I have a Java Problem - It is not locating some package or classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I create just a test over here to try to see what is the problem. But I am very new to Java, Any advice will be much appreciated.

My goal is to make my Main class to call the method from the second class.

**Main Class code:**

```
package Constructors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        test testObject = new test();
        testObject.message();

    }
}
```

---

**Second Class code:**

```
package Constructors;

public class test {

    public void message() {
        System.out.println("Please Work!");
    }
}
```

---

**Error msg:**

```
"C:\Users\Hristiyan Dimov\.jdks\openjdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\PROGRAMS\JAVA-InteliJ IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=53870:D:\PROGRAMS\JAVA-InteliJ IDEA\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Constructors.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Constructors.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Constructors.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: the Image show the end screen of the Program after a "Run" Process]

Comment: I notice the 'out' folder is not being generated where IntelliJ should keep the compiled .class files

Comment: Can you open the menu Build and click "Build Project" and try running the class?

Comment: This doesn't affect functionality, but to improve code readability (which is VERY important as your projects get more complex), follow industry-accepted principles and guidelines. One of such principles are naming conventions. Class names should start with capital letter. For example `Test` instead of `test`.

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one public class in java file, create another file for test class and then try to run it

Comment: Thanks!!
 The problem is solved! 
There was slight problem with wrong renamed Project Folders! :D 
For some reason the IDE is trying to search in old named directory and cuz I am new I didn't know how to manipulate that searching paths.. 
I just needed to create new Project and now everything is working!

Ty all!